# Attempting to add dyno to app hosted with Heroku hobby plan raises error

Tags: heroku

I have a Flask app running on Heroku Hobby - 1 Dyno. When I try to scale my app to 2 dynos I receive this error: "Cannot update to more than 1 Hobby size dynos per process type." The hobby plan says it allows multiple dynos. Why am I getting this error?

```
heroku ps:scale web=2
```

`Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

Comment: What is confusing you about that message? Seems very clear.

Comment: how can I use 2 dynos in my app ? @Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynos cost money on Heroku. If you want more, you have to pay for them.

To [quote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#scalability) Heroku:

> Both horizontal and vertical scale are features of the professional dynos, and are not available to free or hobby dynos.

Professional dynos and their prices can be found [here](https://www.heroku.com/pricing).

**EDIT**

To clarify (as I stated in the comments), you can only have **one** Hobby dyno per app. When it says "Hobby - $7 per dyno/month" it is referring to multiple apps each having a single Hobby dyno, costing $7 per dyno. Not multiple Hobby dynos on a single app. That feature is reserved for the professional dynos only.

Comment: In your link: "Hobby - $7 per dyno/month" . I want yo buy 2 dynos for my app(7x2). How can I do that ?

Comment: @volt It is impossible to horizontally scale hobby dynos with Heroku. They only let you scale the professional dynos (which start at $25/mo). If you want to change your existing dyno, you need to go to your app, head to the Resources tab, then click `Change...` next to 'Hobby Dynos' and select the professional versions.

Comment: @volt When it says 'per dyno per month' it is referring to having multiple apps with a single Hobby dyno each. Not multiple Hobby dynos on a single app.